# Integrable singularity characterisation

Tags: improper-integrals

Suppose that $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $(0,1]$, and moreover that $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx < \infty$$. In this setting, $f$ has an integrable singularity at $0$

My Question: $$f(x)=o(\frac{1}{x})  \text{, as } x \to 0^{+}$$?

Comment: why do you think this is true ?

Comment: The idea was to expand and integrate term by term. If the first term was $1/x$, we would obtain a logarithmic singularity upon integration.